# Marching cubes and greedy meshing

Tags: algorithm, compatibility

Currently i am trying to implement the marching cubes algorithm into my voxel engine to get smoother terrain. My voxel engine also uses the greedy meshing algorithm to optimize the engines meshing. My question is do these two algorithms contradict each other (because one minimizes the vertices which the other uses for smoother terrain)? Or are they intercompatible?

Comment: With `minimize the vertices` you mean `reducing the amount of the vertices...`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to apply the greedy meshing after the marching cube. Don't forget the marching cube has 512 possibilities (or something like that, forgot the exact number) so you'll have to edit your greedy mesh.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can combine greedy meshing and the concepts from Marching Cubes - I've had some success with this as a way to reduce the polygon count. But Marching Cubes tends to result in "cracks" when you move beyond a uniform grid of cubes. For this reason there are some other related algorithms which may be better - such as Dual Contouring - which give you just one vertex per cuboid.

You can read more about my approach in my [Dual Marching Cuboids Github repo](https://github.com/andygeers/DualMarchingCuboids).